# How to display section title for posts only once in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, erb

I'd like to list `Posts` based on their `Section`. And I have written the given code:

**View**

```
<div class="right-links">
    <% @posts.each do |p| %>
        <h3 class="title">
            <%= p.section.title %>
        </h3>

        <p><%= link_to p.title, p %></p>
    <% end %>
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
@posts = Post.limit(15)
```

Obviously this isn't enough and all it does is it displays every post with its section title and that's not really what I want. Is there some tutorial or maybe you guys can help me out how to display the `section title` only once and then all of the posts under it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `group_by` method in the controller.

```
@sections_posts = Post.limit(15).group_by(&:section_id)
```

Then display it in the view

```
<div class="right-links">
    <% @sections_posts.each do |section_id, posts| %>
        <h2 class="title">
            <%= Section.find(section_id).title %>
        </h2>

        <% posts.each do |post| %>
          <p><%= link_to post.title, post %></p>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

That should do it for you.